# Recompile files in matplotlib/src/

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been working with `matplotlib` source and made changes
to some `matplotlib/src/*.cpp` files.
How can I recompile those source files in order to changes take effect?

I tried running

```
python3 setup.py build
```

and

```
python3 -mpip install -ve .
```

as advised in [Contributing section](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/devel/contributing.html#installing-matplotlib-in-developer-mode) of docs but no change observed.

Comment: Both should work, depending how you set up your environment. Which source files did you change and how do you know the changes are not recompiled?

Comment: I've re-run `python3 -mpip install -ve .` and it worked. Thanks!